# CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , is there "else" function?

Tags: php, curl

```
    <?php
function get_random_proxy()
{
    srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $f_contents = file ("proxy.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
    return $line;
}
$proxy = get_random_proxy(); 
            $ch = curl_init(); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,30);
            curl_exec($ch);  
            curl_close($ch);      
    ?>
```

curl will close connection if can not connect within the 30 seconds.

as you can see, i'm using proxy list. however, some proxy ips sometimes have problems to connect within the 30 seconds, and curl is closing connection when can not load in 30 seconds.

i wanna try another ip for curl connect if curl timeout reached. right now, curl is closing everything if ip isn't working. i wanna try another ip. well, could you please suggest me a function?

edited for @rubayeet. added new proxy function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function get($url, $proxy){
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$proxy); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,30);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);  
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response
}

$url = 'example.com';

while(true) {
   $proxy = get_random_proxy();
   $response = get($url, $proxy);
   if ($response === False) continue;
   else break;
}

//do something with $response
```

Comment: thats my proxy function. how can i use it with your function? function get_random_proxy()
{
    srand ((double)microtime()*1000000);
    $f_contents = file ("proxy.txt");
    $line = $f_contents[array_rand ($f_contents)];
    return $line;
}$proxy = get_random_proxy();

Comment: Updated the code. Call get_random_proxy inside a infinite loop, and break out when a response is received.

Answer (score 4):

You just have to use curl_errno to test if CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT occured

Comment: oh yes. thats what i need. i ve never seen that function yet. thanks for great advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new curl session to connect to another proxy. So put a foreach loop around your code and loop through your proxy array.

Also you can use curl_errno() and curl_error() to check for an error (like your timeout).

Maybe it would be useful to set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and load it into a var to modify or work on it.